# Some users are not reading the questions that they are reviewing

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Recently I posted [a question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660748/how-to-use-apples-new-san-francisco-font-on-a-webpage/) that was marked as a duplicate by five users who clearly must not have read any answers to it. The question itself is unique. Nobody had previously asked how to use the SF font specifically. And it has a unique answer as well, if you actually read it.

In trying to make my case in the comments, my comments were deleted. What this *appears* to be is moderators just "backing up" the initial users' judgements without evaluating the question themselves.

If you *only* read the question, it appears to be a another "how do I use `@font-face`" question, but in fact if you read the answer you can clearly see it's not; the answer involves something new called font-name abstraction (which in 10 years as a web developer I have never seen used before). Apple is [proposing to add it to the W3C spec](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Jul/0169.html).

In the case of the SF font, it *cannot* be used (legally) with `@font-face`. The answer provides info about this technique that hasn't been covered on SO before:

- You use it by referencing an abstracted generic system font name that can optionally describe various uses (headline, body, caption, etc).
- it's only supported by Safari in iOS9, at the time of this writing.

I want to point this out because more care should be taken before closing questions, especially ones that could be useful to a lot of people. If a user votes to close a question, **it's important to also read the answer to determine whether a problem is a new one.**

My whole point in adding the question the question to SO was to help other people. Obviously I already had the answer.

Comment: No. A duplicate QUESTION is just that...a duplicate QUESTION.

Comment: Watching downvotes coming in, nobody is reading this. SO has become a judge-first ask questions later site I guess.

Comment: ok, so couple of things here : 1) those who voted to close the question are NOT the same ones who deleted the comments. 2) a duplicate question doesn't close, it stays up as a sign post... 3) if the answer is good, maybe it should be posted on the dupe target?

Comment: @andy how to use the SF font specifically has not been asked yet. you have to acknowledge that if the answer is unique to the question, it's not a duplicate

Comment: For one thing, none of the people who voted to put that question on-hold as a duplicate are actually *"mods"* - that's why it took five of them. The advice here is no different to any other controversial duplicate, you should *edit the question* to clarify why the duplicate doesn't apply.

Comment: Then make the question unique to the SF font. If you question is "what's the trick?", it can be improved.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did! I mentioned the question is for the SF font specifically.  Nobody had previously asked how to use the SF font specifically. And it has a unique answer as well.

Comment: But what you *don't* say is *"I have tried the answers on [possible duplicate], but they don't work in this case because [reasons]"*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I feel like a broken record here, and since you deleted my edit, I'll say it again. This is for the SF font specifically. The answer for my question specifically does not apply to other fonts

Comment: @inorganik I haven't *deleted* it, I *moved* it, so that the question reads more consistently - you don't need to plaster **edit** on things, as the whole history is visible to anyone sufficiently interested. And if you think *you* feel like a broken record, do try to empathise with all of those who keep telling you **then put that *in the question body***. Note that this is likely to be an evolving issue, too - it applies only to SF now, but that will probably not always be the case.

Comment: Also, do please keep the passive-aggression out of your various question edits.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry - this has been a frustrating experience for me. See sequence of events: 1. Figure out solution to unique problem. 2. Post on SO to help other people. 3. SO closes question. 4. Try to get "justice" on meta. 5. Get a million downvotes

Comment: @inorganik you would likely have had a more enjoyable experience if you'd kept the attitude out of it in the first place. Putting a question on hold is just that: **on hold**. It's no longer called *"closed"* because it's a state from which you can (and we hope you will!) recover. There was already information *in the banner* telling you exactly what you should have done, which has been reiterated by numerous users here.

Comment: Voting on meta is different and getting justice doesn't always mean we have to agree with your point of view...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, when someone is reviewing close votes in the queue, all they see is the question, not the answers.  This happens because we are looking to see if the **question** is a dupe.  And your looks like every other "I can't make this font show up in my site" question.

Problem two is how you worded your question.  You haven't done anything there to show that your problem isn't a duplicate of the other one.  You can add something to your question like "I've tried the solutions here and here, but they didn't work".  You should probably also mention that that font is special.  If I saw that in the review queue, it looks like trying to use a Google font or something and thus looks like a dupe.

Consider how this is going to help future visitors.  Will everyone be searching just for the San Francisco font?  Will people know to look for that to figure out how to use all current or future Apple fonts?  If you asked it something like this:

> I am trying to use the Apple font San Francisco in my project.  I've
>   done X, Y and Z but the font still doesn't show up.  There is no URL I can
>   use in CSS to import the font with.  This is also limited to / new in iOS 9.

That would help reviewers see that it isn't the same.  If you want your question re-opened, go edit it to make it clear that it isn't the same.  Then people can vote to reopen it if it warrants it.

Answer (score 10):

> If a mod votes to close a question, it's important to also read the answer to determine if a problem is a new one.

No, it shouldn't be. If the questions are duplicates, then the new answer should be posted on the original question. If it is a different question, then that needs to be made clear *in the question body*, not in an answer.

In this specific case, I think the opening part of your answer:

> Apple's new system font is not publicly exposed. Apple has started abstracting system font names:

along with the text you quoted, belongs in the question.

Comment: "The answer belongs on the original question" - a question with an answer in it isn't a question.

Comment: @inorganik you have misunderstood: when Bill says *"The answer belongs on the original question"*, they mean that (in some cases) you should add your new answer to the old question, rather than creating a new question. This keeps all of the answers in one place, which is much more helpful for future users.

Comment: In this case, no, because the answer applies only to the SF font specifically. I have repeated myself over and over again that this is for the *SF font specifically*. The answer for my question specifically *does not apply to other fonts*

Comment: @inorganik you are being given **two options** in this answer, either: 1. add your new answer to the old question; or 2. edit the new question to clarify *in the question itself* that it is not a duplicate. If we have to address every single controversial duplicate individually we will be here a while, hence the generic form of this answer. Demanding that reviewers look through all of the answers too is *not* appropriate; **questions should stand alone** (and they are reviewed alone - you don't see the answers when reviewing close votes).

Comment: @inorganik You should specify in your question *why* this font is different from the rest. To someone unfamiliar with this particular situation, the "font" is no different from any other font. You explained it well enough in THIS question, why not move some of that explanation over there?

Comment: @billthelizard theoretically, the asker wouldn't have known that though right?

Comment: @inorganik but the asker *should* have done their research, found that other question, tried out the answers there, discovered that they didn't work for this specific font and **mentioned all of that in the question**, which would have removed any ambiguity around it being a dupe. The standards for self-answered questions are the same as for any other.

Comment: @inorganik But they would have figured out (as you did) that something was different about the SF font, and included that in their question to distinguish it from the other question, whose solutions didn't work.

Answer (score 7):

None of the five people who voted to close that question were moderators, therefore they did not have the power to delete comments. Regarding those comments, this is how they went:

[image: Deleted comments]

The only comment not deleted by the author (or by the system on question closure) was one that was deleted by an unrelated moderator. Your comment had been flagged as being "not constructive", perhaps because of "I'll never understand why some people get some kind of twisted joy closing useful questions with useful answers." It was deleted for that reason.

I do think this is a distinct issue from the question it is marked as a duplicate of, so I've reopened your question. In the future, maybe don't attack people who are voting to close a question as a duplicate and instead politely explain why your question is different.

Comment: Clearly I'm unfamiliar with the lingo. Since they moderated my question, I assumed they were moderators. What are they? Thanks for reopening the question. I already had the answer when I posted it and I posted it to help people.

Comment: @inorganik they're normal users, with privileges. SO is largely maintained by normal everyday users like you or I. The only official moderators are people with diamonds ♦ by their names, like Brad, and even they are elected by the community. Also, things operate democratically around here (for the most part), and many actions can be reversed, e.g. closing/re-opening questions, deleting/undeleting questions, etc.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're catching a lot of grief due to the tone of the question, so I'll try to be a little more diplomatic.

For most people on the main site a question that more or less reads:

> How do I use font X on my site?

Very much looks like a duplicate of the loads of other similar @font-face questions. Most users won't take the time to look into the specific font because, for the vast majority of fonts, the specific font doesn't really matter.

To get the question reopened you may want to edit in the fact that you're aware of the @font-face method and the related questions and that it doesn't work for this specific case.